# jpm run command has an invalid manifest

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, jpm

I am following this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Add-on_SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)) to create add-ons for firefox.

When I run `jpm run -b "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe"`,
the console gives me the following warnings:

> 1546371425561   addons.xpi-utils        WARN    addMetadata: Add-on
>   @celestus-firefox-extension is invalid: Error: File
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\3f4ff82f-9dfc-4065-a6c7-7e9719d0c286\extensions@celestus-firefox-extension.xpi
>   does not contain a valid
>   manifest(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIInstall.jsm:557:11) JS Stack
>   trace:
>
> loadManifest@XPIInstall.jsm:557:11
>
> awaitPromise@XPIProvider.jsm:188:3
>
> syncLoadManifestFromFile@XPIInstall.jsm:620:10
>
> addMetadata@XPIDatabase.jsm:2334:21
>
> processFileChanges@XPIDatabase.jsm:2686:21
>
> checkForChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:2581:34
>
> startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2159:25
>
> callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:203:12
>
> _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:652:5
>
> startup@AddonManager.jsm:805:9
>
> startup@AddonManager.jsm:2775:5
>
> observe@addonManager.js:66:9
>
> 1546371425681   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN
>   Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid
>   host permission: resource://pdf.js/
>
> 1546371425681   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN
>   Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid
>   host permission: about:reader*

Firefox opens as expected, but the icon that is supposed to be there is not there.
[image]

I can't find anything that could help me fix that. Some said it was because of a JSONwith an invalid format but everything is clear on my side.

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

edit: Just tried with a console with admin rights, does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just because of a newby mistake. I run firefox dev edition 65.0b7 but this tutorial works for firefox 57 and bellow.

Answer was given [here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/issues/395)